# Maven Central Upstream Sources within Azure DevOps

Tags: maven, azure-devops, maven-plugin, maven-central

Is it possible to to add [Maven Central](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) as an upstream source for an artifact feed in Azure DevOps?

I am currently using Nexus as a proxy to Maven Central but I would like to migrate to Azure DevOps.

It looks like there is a [request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/333091/vsts-maven-can-we-use-public-access-token-to-authe.html) for the functionality, but I wasn't sure if someone was clever enough to solve it with a Maven plugin or something else.

Answer (score 2):

> Maven Central Upstream Sources within Azure DevOps

Indeed, add Upstream Sources for Maven feeds to proxy maven central or other maven repositories is also required by many other customers, check it from:

[Add Upstream Sources for Maven feeds](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365864/add-upstream-sources-for-maven-feeds.html)

And MS team are working on the underlying infrastructure required for Maven upstream sources now, and expect to deliver them early in 2019.

You can find this in the [Azure DevOps Features Timeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/) **2019 Q1**:

[image]

So, it will meet with us soon.

Besides, AFAIK, there is no such way or Maven plugin to resolve this issue at this moment.

Hope this helps.